# Collections of sets with pairwise non-trivial intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a finite collection of finite sets $X= \left \{x_1,...,x_k \right\}$ such that: $\forall$ $i,j$, $x_i \cap x_j \neq \emptyset$. I'm interested in sufficient conditions for the following assertion: $\exists$ $y$ such that $y \in x_i$ $\forall$ $i$.

It's clear that this assertion is not true in general, i.e. take $X= \left\{ \left\{1,2,3 \right \}, \left\{4,3 \right\}, \left \{4,2 \right\} \right\}$, but in some cases it is.

I realize that the lack of structure here is likely the source of my difficulty. It can be shown, however, that if each $x_i \subseteq \left\{ 1,2,...,n \right \}$ and $X$ has said property, then $|X| \leq 2^{n-1}$.

I realize that this question may not be answerable, and if it is, the answer may be lengthy beyond reason. I was just hoping for any sort of insight.

Comment: I don't see how this is of much use, but $\exists y \forall x \in X y \in x$ is equivalent to $X$ having the finite intersection property which is equivalent to $X$ begin contained in a filter. However, it's quite easy to answer how many subsets $X \subseteq \{1, \ldots, k\}$ there are with this property.

Comment: It has to be $\mathcal P(\{1, \ldots, k\})$ in my previous comment.